# Python encoding error in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, json, unicodeencodeerror

I am writing a JSON file, as string input, using python, into a .json file in the file system.
However I am getting the following error sometimes and I don't know why.
Any ideas?

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in
>       position 1920: ordinal not in range(128)

The json file created is used as input in the "JSON To Features" geoprocessing tools and it fails.

```
# Script arguments
inputFeatures_json = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#write to file
jsonFileName = 'WebMap_{}.json'.format(str(uuid.uuid1()))
JSON_File = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, jsonFileName)
f = open(JSON_File , 'w')
f.write(inputFeatures_json)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that your string `inputFeature_json` has special characters that are not in the ascii encoding. If you have characters that are not in the english alphabet they can cause encoding errors. Try to [convert the string as unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182603/python-how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf-8).

for example:

```
# Script arguments
inputFeatures_json = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#wtite to file
jsonFileName = 'WebMap_{}.json'.format(str(uuid.uuid1()))
JSON_File = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, jsonFileName)
f = open(JSON_File , 'w')
f.write(inputFeatures_json.encode("UTF-8"))
```

If you have string with special characters as text in your srcipt add a python ["magic line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077479/how-does-the-magic-liness-in-python-work-when-specifying-encoding-in-python) at the beginning of your srcipt:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
s = u'ÖÄÜ'
```

Comment: this throws an error :  f.write(unicode(inputFeatures_json, "UTF-8"))
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

Comment: try f.write(inputFeatures_json.encode("UTF-8")) if you write it into a file take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483423/how-to-write-unicode-strings-into-a-file

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9942822/1914034

Comment: f.write(inputFeatures_json.encode("UTF-8")) worked. So my code is now :  jsonFileName = 'WebMap_{}.json'.format(str(uuid.uuid1()))
JSON_File = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, jsonFileName)

f = open(JSON_File , 'w')
f.write(inputFeatures_json.encode('utf-8'))
f.close