# selection by location with search cursor

Tags: arcpy, unicodeencodeerror

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

points = r'C:\Users\Temitope\PycharmProjects\Scripts\DATA\ne_10m_populated_places_simple.shp'
countries = r'C:\Users\Temitope\PycharmProjects\Scripts\DATA\ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp'
outpath = r'C:\Users\Temitope\PycharmProjects\Scripts\Output'

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(points, 'points_layer')

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(countries, ['FID', 'SOVEREIGNT']) as country_cursor:
    for x in country_cursor:
        print x[1]
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(countries, 'countries_layer', """ "FID" = {} """.format(x[0]))
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('points_layer', 'WITHIN', 'countries_layer')
        formatted_output_name = x[1].replace('(', '_').replace(')', '_')
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('points_layer', outpath, 'cities_in_{}'.format(formatted_output_name))
        print 'Successfully converted {}'.format(formatted_output_name)

print 'Finished'
```

THIS IS MY OUTPUT:

```
Senegal
Successfully converted Senegal
Saudi Arabia
Successfully converted Saudi Arabia
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Temitope/PycharmProjects/Scripts/gis_scripts/gis_script.py", line 17, in <module>
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('points_layer', outpath, 'cities_in_{}'.format(formatted_output_name))
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe3' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/140112/115

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/292098/edit) to include the complete output, including the output from the `print x[1]` line.

Comment: Try `formatted_output_name = x[1].decode('latin-1').replace('(', '_').replace(')', '_')`

Comment: Luke, i have tried it but still the issue occurs..

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is failing is that you are using .format() with both regular str and a unicode str (the one returned by arcpy.da.searchcursor).

for example this fails in python 2:

```
myustring = unicode('ã', 'utf8')
print 'regular old string plus {}'.format(myustring)
```

but this would work:

```
myustring = unicode('ã', 'utf8')
print u'no longer a regular old string plus {}'.format(myustring)
```

so in your example, this line should fix your problem (changing the first str to unicode):

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('points_layer', outpath, u'cities_in_{}'.format(formatted_output_name))
```

Switching to python 3 (with arcgisPro) would fix these headaches but of course that's not an option for everyone!

Comment: Thank you sir. But as i did the correction as followed, another problem arises again

Comment: Line 18, in <module> print 'successfully converted {}'.format (formatted_output_name)                            UnicodeEncodeError:' ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe3' in position 1: ordinal not in range (128)

Comment: It's the same exact problem, just change the string to unicode: `print u'Successfully converted {}'.format(formatted_output_name)`

Comment: Thank you sir. It works but another situation arises..  
                             Guinea-Bissau

Comment: arcpy. arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('points_layer', outpath, 'cities_in_{}'.format(formatted_output_name))                                                   arcgisscripting. ExecuteError: ERROR 000354: the name contain invalid characters

Comment: It mean Guinea-Bissau contain invalid character (-).. How can i make (-) valid in arcpy. Arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion

Comment: There are many ways. arcpy has a method, ValidateFieldName, built in to do this so you can do `formatted_output_name = arcpy.ValidateFieldName(x[1])` and forgo using .replace().  This would be simple but slow. You could also do regex or something more pythonic like `formatted_output_name = u''.join([char for char in x[1] if char not in '<>:"\/|-?*'])`